# leaflet blank map on phonegap

Tags: cordova, leaflet, openlayers, phonegap

I have a phonegap problem with leaflet. I have a phonegap app which just displays a leaflet map.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-    scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-    densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css" />
<title>Basic Leaflet Mobile Map</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="app">
<div id="map"></div>

</div>
<script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([52.04, -0.73], 12);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
app.initialize();
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Which seems to work perfectly when I do:

```
phonegap serve
```

and I look the page on chrome.

But when I try to look my app via PhoneGap Developper, the map is not loaded... Any idea ? I have all buttons of leaflet tools (zoom, etc) but no map.

Thanks

PS: I have the same issue with openlayers.

Comment: Sounds like a [whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the load of external content, You´re calling a link of a tiled map service, in this case OpenStreetMap :

'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'

due to the security policy of Cordova you need add a whitelist to allow external URLs to the app.

You can do this adding a plugin called ["cordova-plugin-whitelist"](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) then add into you Config.xml the protocols that you will allow

1. Install cordova-plugin-whitelist in your proyect:

   ```
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
   ```
2. In you Config.xml add the allow intents:

   [image]
3. Then run the app on your device or android emulator

Hope it works for you.